# Recover Cloud functions default service account with the undelete POST call

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have used Google Cloud Functions for quite a long time, with no real authentication problem for now.
Today I meet this error while deploying a new function

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Bad Request], message=[Default service account 'PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account.]
```

I tried several things :

- disable/enable GCF API : no service account recovered
- `gcloud beta app repair` [reference here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair)
  No default service account recovered
- the [undelete API POST call](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete?apix_params=%7B"name"%3A"projects%2F-%2FserviceAccounts%2Funique_id"%2C"resource"%3A%7B%7D%7D)

If I understand well the current GCP features, using the last option is my best solution, but somehow I keep getting a 400 error

[image]

I found my unique-id in my log activity at the creation of the default service account

[image]

I really can't see where is the problem in the undelete API call and would be really thankful if you could help with it

Comment: Did you make any change (e.g creating/editing Service Accounts) that could have lead to this situation? Meaning, do you reckon you could have made any change that could have caused this? If so, what was it? How long has this issue been happening for?

Comment: Yes, I did made an unvoluntary delete of this app engine service account, and the issue has been happening since then. My question is more : how do I recover it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Maxim, I know now that my problem comes from the fact that the deleting of this service account happened more than 30 days ago. Which means that it has already been purged from the system and it's not recoverable anymore.

In case you meet this same kind of problem, please try out this link : 
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account

Comment: Hello, I am glad that you have found the solution for your issue. Please mark your answer as answered to give it more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I see three alternative ways in how to proceed here next:

- Create a new project from scratch to work from.
- [File a support case via the support center](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/#filing_cases_via_the_support_center).
- Open a private issue by providing your project number in the following [component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491477).

I believe it's convenient in reaching out GCP Support for help at this stage, and recommend you to do so; seeing as you've attempted most if not all ways of Service Account recovery to no success.

On a last note, as for the latter option, the contents of the private issue will only be visible to you, and to the GCP Support staff (us). If you choose this option, please let me know when it's opened, and I'll start working on it as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok, I will proceed as you ask me. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I created a private issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134732645) @Maxim

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'm having a look now. @hyone