# How to setup an account as the default service account for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have accidentally deleted my default service accounts for firebase and now my functions are unable to access firestore and are returned with the following error.

```
 {"code": "400","details": "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant: Not a valid email or user ID.","metadata": {"internalRepr": {}}}
```

I have created a service account for firebase again with the relevant permissions, but not sure how to set it up as the default account.

Any help would be appreciated. If there is some details missing in the question, I will be happy to add. Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue? If yes, can you share your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For guys struggling with this issue and have **recently deleted** the default service account **(within 30 days)** can go to this link for solution: [When default service account is deleted within 30 days.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983987/trying-to-deploy-firebase-functions-default-service-account-not-found)

If the 30 days window has passed and you're looking for other solutions like creating a new service account and setting it to default, let me tell you,

**"THAT'S NOT POSSIBLE. The only workaround available is create a new project and deploy the service desired there."**.

It's not me who's saying this, that is the expected behaviour. I struggled a lot with this issue, and did not find any solutions online or on any stackoverflow question and neither in their documentation.

Finally there was a answer by ***Maxim*** on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473862/recover-cloud-functions-default-service-account-with-the-undelete-post-call) where I had three alternate ways, one of which was to:

- open a private issue by providing your ***project number*** in the following [component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491477).

So I did open a private issue with Google Issuetracker and this was the response from them:

[image: Google Issuetracker's Response]

Hope this saves someone's time. I struggled with this issue for 2 days. Such a waste of time to come to this conclusion.

Comment: I have to face the same problem, the comment is too late but I can not undelete in 30 days window I got this message "NOT_FOUND: Account deleted: 53324813345"