# Trying to deploy firebase functions, Default service account not found

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to upload the following simple function to my firebase console

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

However, it fails with the following error:

```
HTTP Error: 400, Default service account 'myfirebase-projecte@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account.
```

At this point I am confused between Firebase and Google Cloud Platforms and where this error can be fixed.

Comment: Did you do what it suggests and disable/reenable the Cloud Functions API?  You would have to do this in the Google Cloud console.

Comment: Yes, I have but to no avail.

Comment: @DougStevenson's tip to go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis and disable then re-enable the Functions API was the only thing that worked for me for a similar error: `functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 404, Could not authenticate 'service-####@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com': Not found; Gaia id not found for email service-####@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Thanks for sharing and adding to the picture! I had to restore my default service account. I elaborate on that below on my self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from the rabbit hole! I figured it out. Seems like I accidentally deleted my Default Service Account (thankfully within 30 days) and I was able to recover it by following these very specific and very useful instructions https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting since it's not possible to re-activate using the console's interface.

Basically, you have to find when the deletion occured, get the account's ID from this event and then restore it using the Google Cloud terminal with the `gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete [ACCOUNT_ID]` command. Phew!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: For guys trying to create a new service account and setting it to default as their 30 days window has passed, do checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474965/how-to-setup-an-account-as-the-default-service-account-for-firebase/62317243#62317243

Answer (score 0):

Firebase uses Google Cloud Platform (GCP) to run Cloud Functions. This error message is telling you that something's wrong with your GCP setup. So, try what the error message says: go to the Google Cloud project you've linked your Firebase project to [here](https://console.cloud.google.com), and turn the Cloud Functions API off and back on. If that doesn't work, you might want to make sure the Firebase CLI you're deploying from is logged in correctly (run `firebase login` to check), and has access to the project -- that can sometimes cause issues.

Comment: I tried both disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions APi as well as logging out and logging back in through the CLI with `firebase logoout` and `firebase login`. Still getting the same error upon `firebase deploy`.

Comment: I visited the App Engine Service Accounts pages and cannot create a service account with an `@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` ending. What should I do now?